# Change beginning of each image src with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image

I am trying to use Javascript to change the beginning of each image src before the page loads.

I would want to change

```
src="v/image1.jpg"
src="v/image2.jpg"
src="v/image2.jpg"
```

to

```
src="http://different-server.com/v/image1.jpg"
src="http://different-server.com/v/image2.jpg"
src="http://different-server.com/v/image3.jpg"
```

Is there any way of doing that to all of the images of a certain class? Or would I have to create a loop that does this?

Thank you.

Comment: no matter how you write this, a loop **WILL** have to be used, whether you write an explict for/each, or call a function which will just use its own internal looping.

Comment: What have you tried? There are many, many examples out there of using jQuery to do exactly this sort of thing. Have you found they don't work for you in some way?

Comment: @MarcB The solution will involve a loop, but not necessarily one that OP has to write. The question was "would I have to create a loop that does this"?

Comment: Before the page loads is a little late. The browser will already be fetching the image by the time you can change it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code works :

```
$.each($("img"), function( index, value ) {
    srcValue = "http://different-server.com/" + $(this).attr("src")
    $(this).attr("src", srcValue)
});
```

See jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wkf3cpe9/

Comment: Thank you. I originally wanted to use Javascript but your JQuery solution worked best for me.

Answer (score 1):

You may do like this:

```
var srcElement = document.getElementsByClassName('your_class');
for(var i=0;i<srcElement.length;i++){
  srcElement[i].src = "http://different-server.com/" + srcElement[i].src
}
```

Comment: OP said they want to target images with a certain class.